# Чтение параметров из INI файла

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Подскажите как прочитать параметры из `INI` файла, таким образом, чтобы при загрузке формы они использовались для `checkBox`

Используется класс `IniFile.cs` подробнее: [link](https://gist.github.com/DamianSuess/e8bf4679b201e07757e97aad944e0395)

Данный класс позволяет читать значения в файле `INI` кодом:

```
var checkBox1 = IniFile.Read("checkBox1", "app-ini");
```

Так в файле `INI` выглядит значение:

```
[app-ini]
checkBox1=true
```

Проблема в том, что когда я помещаю код в `Form1_Load` появляется ошибка *"Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства `"IniFile.Read(string, string)"` требуется ссылка на объект"* (пришлось поменять среднюю строчку таким образом):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ini = new IniFile(@"C:\Settings.ini");
    var checkBox1 = ini.Read("checkBox1", "app-ini"); // изменено IniFile.Read на ini.Read
    checkBox1.Checked = ?
}
```

Теперь зашел в тупик, как прочитать из файла значение `true` и подставлять его для `checkBox1` при запуске формы `Form1_load`

Comment: в отладчике какое значение у Вашей переменной checkBox1 после выполнения ini.Read()?

Comment: Это должно работать как на `user.config` вот пример: http://postimg.cc/VrL1q4cp (если я правильно понял то в параметрах приложения `Имя - Save1` + `Тип - bool` + `значение - False`)

Comment: с большой долей вероятности `checkBox1` - у вас string, так преобразуйте его в bool. `checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(checkBox1);`

Comment: Лучше б ты не использовал эту библиотеку...

Comment: @Qwertiy не подскажете почему? автор упоминал `вы можете свободно использовать ее`, или дело в работе кода?

Comment: @Vitokhv, дело в коде. Она читает ключи через winapi, т. е. каждый раз, когда ты запрашиваешь значение, читается весь файл целиком (ну если повезёт и ключ где-то в начале, то, наверное, не весь). Гораздо эффективнее один раз прочитать файл и запомнить в памяти, а оттуда уже брать значения.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение, пока меня устроит такой вариант, сохранений не много, всего на 10 строк, просто другое для меня очень сложно в понимании...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ini = new IniFile(@"C:\Settings.ini");
    var checkBox1Str = ini.Read("checkBox1", "app-ini");
    checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(checkBox1Str);// конвертируем стринг в бул и присваиваем
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает - около 8 часов сидел думал...) три браузера полных вкладок, а тут так просто оказалось...)